# Keydown event behavior when holding down Shift key

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard, dom-events, keydown

I noticed that when you press and hold a letter key like <kbd>A</kbd> the keydown event is fired continuously as long as you hold it. However when you press and hold down <kbd>shift</kbd>, the event is fired only once. I want to base my application logic on that observation, but I don't know if it is a standard behavior in every browser. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Comment: I don't see why shift would ever need to be "auto-spammable". Unless you actually need to react to a shift press directly, you're probably better off ignoring shift presses, then checking the event modifiers when a letter is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not a standard behaviour that you can rely on. I did a quick test on a few browsers I had installed (IE Edge, IE 11, Chrome 55, all on a windows machine), where all 3 browsers auto-repeated the keydown event for both letter keys (like `A`), and modifier keys (like `shift`), contrary to what you state your browser does.

Consistent handling of keyboard events has always been difficult across different browsers, as documented  by [Jan Wolter here](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html) and [Peter-Paul Koch here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html). Wolter writes about auto-repeat:

> If a key is held down long enough it typically auto-repeats, and some additional events will be triggered on each autorepeat. On Macintosh and Linux systems, modifier keys usually don't auto-repeat, but on Windows systems they do

then Wolter goes on to list various exceptions to this.

Comment: I'm using Linux so that makes sense. Thank you.